# NetworkX directed chart - Colour nodes based on their weight value

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx, directed-graph

I have an issue with assigning colour to the nodes on below attached graph. The node colours need to be adjusted accordingly based on a divergent format (RdYlGn) based on the node weight.

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("D:\\Cars0319SP.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame({'from':data['Car Code - Serviced'], 'to':data['Car Code - Due Serv'],'value': data['Car Make - Serviced']}) #Value is categorical

df['value'] = pd.Categorical(df['value'])
print(df['value'].cat.codes)
colormake = df['value'].cat.codes
colorlist = ['cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'black']

G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='from', target='to', edge_attr=True, create_using=nx.DiGraph())
G.to_directed(as_view=True)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=False, node_color=colormake, node_size=((df['value'].cat.codes)*12), node_fontsize='4', edge_color= 'mediumpurple', arrowstyle='->', arrowsize=5, width=2.0, edge_cmap=plt.cm.jet, arrows=True)
plt.show()
```

The result I'm getting with having eg. `node_color = 'wheat'`is:

[image: Image 1]

EDIT: Dataset included to help reproduce the error

```
Car Code - Due Serv  Car Code - Serviced    Car Make - Serviced   Veh.In
      N155          
      U193          
      P169                  N155                    32N155           2
      F194                  P169                    32P169           1 
      N155          
      B712                  F194                    32F194           2
```

When I'm inserting the "colormake" string into node colour, I'm getting the below error.

```
ValueError: 'c' argument has 259 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size 195, 'y' with size 195.
```

Surely I'm doing something wrong in defining the various colours within the code, your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show the first 5 rows from your Dataframe `df` so that we can try and reproduce your error?

Comment: Thank you, I've just added the dataset.